# Problem moving camera to the right direction in Unity, using parallax and MoveToward

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Cinemachine camera that needs to follow the player swiping left and right using the new input system. To my CM camera, I have attached the following components:

- A script called Camera Swipe
- A player input component, which maps to a default map called Swipe Map, in a Screen Controls asset
- A script called Screen Input Manager

The screen input manager code is below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[DefaultExecutionOrder(-1)]

public class ScreenInputManager : MonoBehaviourSingleton<ScreenInputManager>
{
    public GameObject player;

    #region
    public delegate void StartTouch(Vector2 position, float time);
    public event StartTouch OnStartTouch;
    public delegate void EndTouch(Vector2 position, float time);
    public event StartTouch OnEndTouch;
    #endregion

    private ScreenControls screenControls;
    private Camera mainCamera;

    private void Awake()
    {
        screenControls = new ScreenControls(); // new instance of input manager
        screenControls.SwipeMap.Enable();
        screenControls.Enable();
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        screenControls.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        screenControls.Disable();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryContact.started += context => StartTouchPrimary(context);
        screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryContact.canceled += context => EndTouchPrimary(context);
    }

    private void StartTouchPrimary(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (OnStartTouch != null) OnStartTouch(Utils.ScreenToWorld(mainCamera, screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryPosition.ReadValue<Vector2>()), (float)context.startTime); // avoid using screen to world here, do it later 
    }

    private void EndTouchPrimary(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (OnEndTouch != null) OnEndTouch(Utils.ScreenToWorld(mainCamera, screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryPosition.ReadValue<Vector2>()), (float)context.time); // avoid using screen to world here, do it later 
    }

    public Vector2 PrimaryPosition()
    {
        return screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryPosition.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }
}
```

The Camera Swipe code is below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

[DefaultExecutionOrder(-1)]

public class CameraSwipe : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float minimumDistance = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float maximumTime = 1f;
    [SerializeField, Range(0f, 1f)] private float directionThreshhold = 0.9f;

    // private ScreenInputManager inputSystem;

    private Vector2 startPosition;
    private float startTime;
    private Vector2 endPosition;
    private float endTime;
    private Vector3 targetPosition;

    private ScreenInputManager inputProvider;
    private CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCamera;
    private Rigidbody2D cameraRigid;
    private Transform cameraTransform;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputProvider = GetComponent<ScreenInputManager>();
        virtualCamera = GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
        cameraRigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        cameraTransform = virtualCamera.VirtualCameraGameObject.transform;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        inputProvider.OnStartTouch += SwipeStart;
        inputProvider.OnEndTouch += SwipeEnd;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        inputProvider.OnStartTouch -= SwipeStart;
        inputProvider.OnEndTouch -= SwipeEnd;
    }

    private void SwipeStart(Vector2 position, float time)
    {
        startPosition = position;
        startTime = time;
    }


    private void SwipeEnd(Vector2 position, float time)
    {
        endPosition = position;
        endTime = time;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(startPosition, endPosition) >= minimumDistance && (endTime - startTime) <= maximumTime)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(startPosition, endPosition, Color.red, 5f);
            Vector3 direction = endPosition - startPosition; // halfway between start and end?

            targetPosition = cameraTransform.position; 
            targetPosition.x =  -direction.x;
            Vector2 direction2D = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y).normalized;
            SwipeDirection(targetPosition, direction2D);
        }
    }

    private void SwipeDirection(Vector3 direction, Vector2 direction2D)
    {
        if (Vector2.Dot(Vector2.left, direction) > directionThreshhold)
        {
            
            Debug.Log("left " + " the direction 2d is: " + direction2D);
            cameraTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cameraTransform.position, direction, Time.deltaTime * (float) 3);

        }

        else if (Vector2.Dot(Vector2.right, direction) > directionThreshhold)
        {
            Debug.Log("right " + " the direction 2d is: " + direction2D);
            cameraTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cameraTransform.position, direction, Time.deltaTime * (float) 3);
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem** - The issue is that it seems to detect a left swipe sometimes when I'm swiping right, and sometimes it seems to stall and not go past certain parts of the screen. It seems to not be picking apart left swipes from right ones easily.

**What I've tried:** - I think it might be to do with calling SwipeDirection in Update(), when it really should just be called at the end of SwipeEnd(). But when I do that, then because it's not continually updated, the camera only moves a tiny bit and not fluidly at all.

I've also tried to do a bunch of Debug.Logs. It seems to stall when the variable Direction2D (in the second code block) is equal to "0". Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: For a swipe direction, I would think that taking the position on current frame compared to the position of previous frame would give the most accurate results.  You may need to  take a running average to avoid small changes affecting the direction trend.  The biggest issue above seems to be the use of `endPosition` which is not set until the swipe is complete, but is used in Update.

Comment: Thank you. I haven’t been able to figure out how to wait until the swipe is complete, and only then run the camera movement in update. Would you have any ideas? Thanks for your help.